# Adding a class on selected menu item

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu.

```
     <div id="ReportMenu" class="left-box" style = "width: 250px;">
            <p class="section-title">
               <span>Select Report : </span>
            </p>
               <ul id="left-box" class="menu-left-box">
                    <li id="menu_1" class="selected"><a href="#"  onclick="getPartial(1);">A</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_2"><a href="#" onclick="getPartial(2);">B</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_3"><a href="#" onclick="getPartial(3);">C</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_4"><a href="#" onclick="getPartial(4);">D</a></li>                      
    </ul>   
     </div>
```

I need to make menu item bold when a user clicks on that menu item. When User clicks on some other menu item, class on previous menu item should be removed.
     I will have to write Jquery code in getPartial() method.

How can i do this?

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getPartial(variable)
{$(".menu-left-box li").css("font-weight","normal");
$(".menu-left-box li:eq("+(variable-1)+")").css("font-weight","bold");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hi now you can used `jquery` function
as like this

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ef365/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="ReportMenu" class="left-box" style = "width: 250px;">
            <p class="section-title">
               <span>Select Report : </span>
            </p>
               <ul id="left-box" class="menu-left-box">
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>                      
    </ul>   
     </div>
```

**Css**

```
.selected{
font-weight:bold;
    font-size:45px;

}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#left-box > li").click(function(){
        $("#left-box > li").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

        })


});
```

**Live demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ef365/1/

Comment: Rohit, this is a good example you gave. But I already have an "Onclick = GetPartial(1)" function for each menu item. And I want to write the Jquery code which you suggested in this function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function getPartial(n) {
    $(".menu-left-box li a").css("font-weight","normal");
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
}
```